# PHP & MYSQL: php is not finding the image path given by mysql

Tags: php, mysql

uploading an image from sitename1.com  and saving image path in mysql as "../sitename2/images/imagename.jpg" but when trying to display that image from different domain like sitename2.com, it's not finding the path remotely while working in localhost.I'm using IIS web server. Please help......

file name: image.php
Domain: sitename1.com
IIS website Physical path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename1

```
$img_file = basename($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
        $folderName = "../sitename2/images/";
        $ext = pathinfo($img_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filePath = $folderName. rand(10000, 990000). '_'. time().'.'.$ext;
    if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" || $ext=="gif" || $ext=="png"){  
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"],    $filePath)) {mysqli_query($conn,......................
```

file name: displayimage.php
Domain: sitename2.com
IIS website Physical path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename2

```
$UploadFile = $row['UploadFile'];
echo'<img src="' . $UploadFile . '" height="50" width="50" class="pic"/>';
```

basically i am using 1st domain to only upload images and using 2nd to display it

sitename1.com only for customer
sitename2.com only for admin

Comment: so where is the code to `insert/update` database records? where is the code where you `SELECT`  that data? where is values of file name stored in database and extracted from database??

Answer (score 0):

So you want to access shared resources from two separate domains?  I think you'll need to setup a shared folder or [virtual directory](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308150/en-us).  This can also be called a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).  Otherwise you would need to copy the assets from a folder under site1 to site2.

From your question it is not clear you understand how the local file system relates to your web URIs.  If you can get a file to load on both domains, say `c:\www\site1\images\imgA.png` and `c:\www\site2\images\imgB.png` at `http://site1.localhost/images/imgA.png` and `http://site2.localhost/images/imgB.png` respectively, or something similar, then you are half way there!  All you need to do is "link" the files in the folder.  If you can't get that far then we need more info on specifically where its falling down.

Comment: value for $uploadfile = ../sitename2/images/35720_1423607967.jpg    ----this is how maysql is saving the image path.